# Is there thing/things that I should do first before using customized types on hashmap?

Tags: java, collections

I want to use a collection to host my data pairs, the order isn't important, duplicate values are allowed and I need fast operation/indexing, so I chose hashmap.

My question is, do I have to override something first before using it like this?

```
Hashmap<string, myOwnDataType> mhashmap = new Hashmap ();
```

For example, in TreeSet, I need to override the comparator in order to use my own customized data type, what preparations should I do in the case of Hashmap???

Comment: The javadoc is the best place to find answers to these questions. In your case (String keys) you don't have to do anything.

Comment: You don't need to do anything if you are performing operations like sorting based on keys (using string), if it is based on values then you should use comparator to perform such sorting in myOwnDataType.

Comment: @assylias no no no, I want string to be the key, and myOwnDataType  to be the value, don't I need to at least override a comparator ?

Comment: @RajuSharma do I need to have my myOwnDataType implement comparable then???

Comment: @VictorCharlie23, yes, if you would like to perform some sorting , based on values .. then yes

Comment: @RajuSharma  So it's "no" for me then because I really don't need sorting of any kind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're all set. String has its own comparator. But please add `<>` (to avoid a type safety warning) and use upper and lower case correctly:

```
HashMap<String, MyOwnDataType> mHashMap = new HashMap<>();
```

Answer (score 1):

Two types are involved in a map: the type of the keys and the type of the values. To use your own class as the value type you don't have to do anything. This holds for `HashMap` as well as for `TreeMap`.

However, to use your own type as the key type in a `HashMap` you do have to consider the following two things:

- A `HashMap` uses the methods `hashCode()` and `equals()` to find key-value pairs and to determine whether two keys are equal. Both methods are implemented in `Object`, but in most cases you will want to override `hashCode()` and `equals()` and make sure they are consistent with each other (that means that when `a.equals(b)` is true, then `a.hashCode() == b.hashCode()`.
- When an object is used as a key in the map, it cannot change anymore (with respect to `hashCode()` and `equals()`. Often, keys used in a hash map are immutable.

Strings, which you use in your example, can be used as keys in a `HashMap` without problems.